# How to pull dependencies from network folder

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-3, gradle-plugin

We have a lot of dependencies in a network folder (let's call it *\dep-set.io.org*) organized like this:

```
\\\\dep-set.io.org\[project]\[version]\[build]\artifact.jar
```

We are planning to move to a RepositoryManager (Artifactory or Nexus) but in the meantime I need to be able to pull those dependencies using Maven or Gradle but I couldn't find a way to do it.
Looks like Maven provides me a way to customize the Build lifecycle but I couldn't find where is doing the actual request for the artifact and how to override that mechanism.

Gradle isn't helping that much, the repositories supported are Maven, Ivy or Local but not through a network though have to assume that I didn't research much on Gradle filesystem support.

I would like to define my dependencies in a certain way that allows me to mark these *special* dependencies as *downloadable from network folder* with certain layout

Thanks

Comment: If you migrate the first step should be to deploy those artifacts into a repository manager and afterwards define those as usual dependencies to get your build running.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're looking for a temporary solution. If so, such a temporary solution could be to use 
`<dependency>
<groupId>zzz</groupId>
<artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
<version>xxx</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>/path/to/artifact</systemPath>
</dependency>`

This will take the dependency on the filesystem.
A bash script or something like that could quickly generate for you all the dependencies you need to add to your pom.xml.

Comment: @Melou I have followed your suggestion before I started to analyze the possibility of requesting dependencies from a network folder, using the systemPath functionality it works but that means that I have to download the dependencies before or can I put a `file://` path in the tag?

Comment: @khmarbaise We are planning to do that, is just that we are in a corporate world and things take much time to happen. I was looking for a solution from a build tool perspective. Thanks

Comment: @martosoler I never tryed with file://. I gues this should work